# widgetset not found with Vaadin 7 on embedded jetty

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

[image]I had following annotation in my servlet class:

```java
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true) 

@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = true, ui = LoginUI.class,  
    widgetset=" com.abc.xyz.widgetset.AppWidgetset")
    // heartbeatInterval=1, closeIdleSessions=true,
```

My UI class contains following annotation:

```java
@WebServlet(value = "/home/*", asyncSupported = true)
```

I had following dependency:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Got EXCEPTION:

> [/VAADIN/widgetsets/src.main.webapp.VAADIN.AppWidgetSet/src.main.webapp.VAADIN.AppWidgetSet.nocache.js] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.

AppWidgetset.gwt.xml file location: **.\src\main\webapp\VAADIN\AppWidgetset.gwt.xml**

```
\---src
    +---main
    |   +---webapp
    |   |   \---VAADIN
    |   |       \---AppWidgetset.gwt.xml
```

Output folder:
**\target\proj\VAADIN\widgetsets\com.mcx.edms.widgetset.AppWidgetset**

When I'm running my application with tomcat or jetty, its working fine but its ***not working on embedded jetty***

@Morfic

Comment: [`vaadin-client-compiled`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/getting-started/getting-started-libraries.html) is not required if you compile you widgetset. Also `@Widgetset(value = "src.main.webapp.VAADIN.AppWidgetSet")
` should be `com.abc.xyz.widgetset.AppWidgetset
` as it represents the package where the compiled files are found and implicitly depends on the package where your `AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml` is. Next you have `AppWidgetset` on your servlet and `AppWidgetSet` on your UI so please be aware that it's case sensitive. Lastly check your output folder to ensure it was compiled

Comment: I did the same thing and unfortunately it is not working.:(

Comment: Please update your question with the new code and log after the above mentioned changes. Also, let us know where in your project structure AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml (or AppWidgetset.gwt.xml whichever you chose) is, and check your output folder to see if the widgetset was compiled (eg: `target\classes\VAADIN\widgetsets\com.abc.xyz.widgetset.AppWidgetset\ `). You can add some screenshots for these 2 things to make it easier for us to see your exact structure. P.S. when you reply to someone's comment you can use `@username` so they get a notification ;-)

Comment: I meant you could use `@username` in comments, like this one, not when editing the question ;-). Nonetheless, as far as I know, the vaadin-maven-plugin scans the compile-source-roots for modules (see the [`getModules()` method](https://github.com/vaadin/maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt/AbstractGwtModuleMojo.java#L85)) and the resulting name will also include the package. So if won't find it under `src\main\webapp\VAADIN\AppWidgetset.gwt.xml` and even if it did, not with the `com.abc.xyz.widgetset` package.

Comment: Usually the `.gwt.xml` file resides in a package under `/src/main/java` or `src/main/resources`, which would explain your resulting `com.abc.xyz.widgetset.AppWi‌​dgetset`. So, you either have multiple `AppWidgetset.gwt.xml` in your project, or a weird project configuration or some typos. For example, why is there a `proj` in your output folder `\target\proj\VAADIN` ? Please try to cleanup the question, including the exception message you're getting (it should have changed when you updated the package name) and let us know so we can have a clearer picture about what's happening.

Comment: Can you post a more complete version of your pom.xml? Or consider creating a new Multimodule setup for new Vaadin add-on project and compare the directory structure with `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-widget -DarchetypeVersion=7.4.6` (DarchetypeVersion = the version of vaadin you are using) HTHs

Comment: I found the answer: I need to mention parameter in JettyWebAppContext as "webContext.setInitParameter("widgetset", "com.abc.xyz.widgetset.AppWidgetset");"

btw, thanks @Morfic

Comment: Great news! When you have the time, perhaps you could consider cleaning up the question with correct packages and info, maybe also add a description of what _embedded jetty_ means in your context, then post your answer and chose it as the correct one, to help anyone else who might have the same issue.